# "{}" what does this mean in the below function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

some of these code I understand but "{}" what does this mean...??

```
var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
        this.el = el || {};
        this.multiple = multiple || false;

        // Variables
        var link = this.el.find('.link');
        // Eventos
        link.on('click', {el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple},this.dropdown)
    }
```

Comment: `el` should become an object if its undefined, otherwise remain el

Comment: in javascript `{}` is called as `object literal notation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// if "this.el" didn't exist, assign it to an empty object {}
this.el = this.el || {};
console.log(el);
```

Try it here: http://goo.gl/CkRlNB

Comment: This is an explanation for the wrong code.  This is a common design pattern, but is not what the OP's question is about.  The OP's code is `this.el = el || {};` which does something DIFFERENT than your code and your explanation.  Perhaps the upvoters didn't realize that this does not even answer the question asked.

Comment: I agree it's different, but I answered for a generic use of it, not just a specific code. I think that will help better. It's just 1 line, I'm sure the OP realize the difference and give it some thoughts.

Answer (score 8):

`{}` in this context means an empty Javascript object (the same as `new Object()`) with no custom properties or methods on it.

So, this statement:

```
// if el contains a value, do this.el = el, otherwise init this.el to an empty object
this.el = el || {};
```

is logically equivalent to this:

```
if (el) {
    this.el = el;   // initialize from function argument
} else {
    this.el = {};   // initialize to an empty object
}
```

Or in words, ***"if `el` contains a non-empty/non-null truthy value, then assign it to `this.el` otherwise, initialize `this.el` with an empty object"***.

It is a shortcut notation to initalize a variable with the first one in the list that is truthy because Javascript's `||` operator evaluates until it finds the first truthy operand and then stops the evaluation and takes that operand as the value.

Answer (score 2):

It means a JavaScript object with no methods or properties.